# Elasticsearch aggregation by multiple indices

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, aggregation-framework

I have some MongoDB collections:

Stories:

```
{
    title: { type: String },
    text: { type: String }
}
```

Comments:

```
{
    text: { type: String },
    story: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Stories" }
}
```

Likes:

```
{
    story: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Stories" }
}
```

This collections are indexed by Elasticsearch. So I need to filter Stories in Elasticsearch by likes and comments.

**Example data.**

```
Stories: 
{
  "title": "First story",
  "text": "This must be the MOST popular story..."
}

{
  "title": "Second story",
  "text": "This story is popular too, but not as the first story."
}

{
  "title": "Third story",
  "text": "This is a unpopular story, because dont have any comment or like"
}


Comments:
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "story": ObjectId("First Story ID")
}

{
  "title": "Foobar",
  "story": ObjectId("First Story ID")
}

{
  "title": "Bar",
  "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID")
}


Likes:
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }

{ "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID") }

{ "story": ObjectId("Third Story ID") }
```

The result of filtering should be like this:

1. First story (4 likes, 2 comments)
2. Second story (2 likes, 1 comment)
3. Third story (1 like)

Is it real to make it with Elasticsearch? And how i can to this?

PS. Why did I choose not to filter with Mongo? Because Mongo shows very slow result of such aggregation.

PPS. Mongo aggregation code of this task:

```
db.getCollection('stories').aggregate([
{$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"comments"}},
{$lookup:{from:"likes",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"likes"}},
{$project: { title: 1, text: 1,comments:1,likes:1, count: { $add: [ {$size: "$comments"}, {$size: "$likes"} ] } } },
{$sort:{"count":-1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your scoring criteria?

Anyway, I would just implement this as two separate [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and merge the result on client side. It should be possible to model this as [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) relationship but it would be a lot more complex without that significant upsides.

You could get top 10 most liked stories on first query, and then get comment aggregations for just those ids ([filtering values with exact values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values)).